# Can you network between ECS Fargate tasks using the container name as hostname?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-compose, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, aws-fargate

I was handed a docker image which previously was being deployed using `docker compose` and because of that it could connect to the database using `db-containername` as the database's hostname. Now that I'm trying to deploy these containers as ECS Fargate tasks however I'm getting `UnknownHostException: db-containername`.

Is there a way that this can be fixed from the outside without changing the underlying image? And if I do have to rebuild the image how should this be done ideally?

Comment: What netnwroking mode are you using with ecs? `awsvpc`?

Comment: @Marcin Yes, that appears to be the only option when using Fargate.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be running a database in Fargate. That said, are these containers running in the same ECS task, or in separate tasks/services?

Comment: @MarkB I agree with you. This is just a trial migration. As a consequence I can freely chose whether to place the containers in the same service or in different services. But feeding changes back into the image which is currently still getting deployed in a different context is tough.

Comment: Well the answer is completely different depending on if the containers are in the same ECS Task or not. On Fargate any containers in the same ECS task can address each other at `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` on their respective ports. If they are running in *different* Tasks then you would need to enable AWS ECS Service Discovery and use the VPC private DNS names of the services.

Comment: @MarkB Knowing that the database can be found at `localhost` doesn't help me. The image is written such that the container tries to connect to `db-containername`, not `localhost`. I'm unable to find a way to change that from outside the image.

Comment: Then you need to edit how the image is created. If the image is created only so that it works in `docker-compose`, then it really isn't going to work in any other cloud computing environment either. The container should be updated so that the database hostname is passed in as an environment variable. In docker-compose that could continue to be `db-containername` but in other environments you could then set it to the correct value.